# Sublime Text 2 wrapping selection in tag

Tags: tags, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, word-wrap

In ST2, highlighting some text and pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> (on Windows) will wrap the current selection in `<p></p>` tags. But is there a way to specify *which* tag to wrap with? Because maybe I want to wrap in a span, or a div instead.

Comment: Try emmet http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/

Comment: @Chef Thanks, that's done the trick. I've added this as an answer below.

Comment: @Chef should be the one adding the answer.

Comment: @AGS Well what do you want me to do about it? Delete mine?

Comment: Emmet works, but just as an additional note. I believe the `ctrl+shift+w` binding simply inserts a snippet. It then places the cursors within the created tags. You should be able to enter any arbitrary content for the tag from there.

Comment: skuroda is right, I was able to just start typing the tag I wanted with plain old ctrl+shift+w and it replaced the p that was the default.

Comment: Default is `Alt`+`Shift`+`w` to wrap tags. Your shortcut closes the entire window with all tabs on Windows. I lost all undo capability for trying that out.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Using Emmet, place the cursor in the tag you want to wrap and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> (for MacOS) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (for Windows), a box will pop up to enter the type of tag you want to wrap with.

Comment: Why my tab is closing when I use the above shortcut?

Comment: Are you on windows? Try Alt-Shift-W. In windows, ctrl + w is a shortcut for close tab.

Comment: If you'r using sublime text on windows with the Emmet package installed, you need to use Shift+Ctrl+G

Comment: on Sublime Text 3 it worked with CTRL + SHIFT + G as well as with ALT + SHIFT + W

Comment: don't accidentally hit CMD + W on mac like I just did. It closes the tab.

Comment: On mac it's `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`W`

Comment: Emmet is not required for this.

Comment: On my Mac it works as you said. Cool that you can also use emmet in the wrap tag section. Such an awesome plugin.

Comment: Emmet's great. I love it, but you don't need it for this feature. See @janaspage's response on this page.

Comment: For mac ctrl+shift+W wraps with an 'inline element', and ctrl+W a block element (with indent)

Answer (score 26):

**Single line**

If you want to convert this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

to this

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

do this:

- Select the text, or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (it will select the current line)
- Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>
- Type the desired tag (it will overwrite the default p tag)

**Multiple lines**

If you want to convert this

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

to this

```
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
```

do this:

- Select the text, or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> multiple times
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (it will make one selection per line)
- Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>
- Type the desired tag (it will overwrite the default p tag)

You can also select the text using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>MOUSE RIGHT BUTTON</kbd>, and in this case you can skip the second step.

**Using Emmet**

If you want to convert this

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

to this

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item1"><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item2"><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item3"><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

do this:

- Select the text
- Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> ([wrap with abbreviation](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#wrapping-individual-lines))
- Type nav>ul.nav>li.nav-item$*>a

*Note for Mac users:*

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> = <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Wow. This is a much better answer :)

Answer (score 7):

The answers are all good. Here is where key bindings are for customizing:

In **Preference: Key Bindings - Default**:

```
{ 
  "keys": ["ctrl+shift+w"], "command": "insert_snippet", 
  "args": { "name": "Packages/XML/long-tag.sublime-snippet" } 
}
```

If you have Emmet, the emmet version is

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+w"], "command": "wrap_as_you_type"}
```

Edit them in **Preferences: Key Bindings - User** to your liking,

Answer (score 5):

Create a custom snippet, for example, to insert a span tag. Go to the app menu: `Tools > New Snippet ...`, and copy to the window the snippet below:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<span style="color:#0000FF">$SELECTION$1</span>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>span</tabTrigger>
    <description>HTML - span - color - blue</description>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

... then save the snippet to file with e.g. `html-span--color` name and bind that snippet to a key combination in `Preferences > Key Bindings-User`, creating a new key entry, for example:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+c"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/User/html-span--color.sublime-snippet" } }
```

It is supposed that a location of the snippet is `Packages/User/` directory.

Now select any text that you need to wrap in the span tag and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or type 'span', press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, a cursor will be set to required position within the tag, just type your text.

I have successfully tested the snippet and key binding with Sublime Text 3 in Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: This seems to have moved in SublimeText3: now it is behind `Tools > Developer > New Snippet...`

Answer (score 1):

to make your life easy while you are in Sublime text3:
type any of these(***p, h1,  div,  header,  footer, title***...) and hit ***Tab***
for example if you want ***div*** Just type div and hit ***Tab***

Comment: This doesn't really help in this instance because the OP is talking about wrapping _existing text_ in a tag, not starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

in ST2 type a tag without brackets and hit Tab. It will automatically give you open and closed tag

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for answering a question. Would you please provide more context for your answer. Also, more tips may be found in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

This system of inserting snippets is very cumbersome compared to the mechanism provided in Dreamweaver. In that case you build a snippet of any kind. It is stored in an in-RAM library and displayed in a directory-style structure. You declare whether the snippet is of type INSERT (at cursor position), or of type SPAN (span selected text). In the first case the entire snippet is inserted. In the second case the snippet is created with a "before" part and and an "after" part. Typically the "after" part is just the closing tag. To use INSERT HERE mode, you position the cursor, and double-click on the snippet in the library and it inserts it at cursor position. To use SPAN SELECTED TEXT mode, highlight the text you want, and double-click the snippet in the library. The selected text is surrounded by the "before" and "after" parts of the snippet.
This is very intuitive, easy to use, and enables the user to build unlimited kinds of snippets which can span selected text.
WOULD SOME VERY SMART PROGRAMMER PLEASE BUILD AN EXTENSION LIKE THIS FOR SUBLIME 3 ?
Note: In comparison, Bracket Highlighter is a Sublime plugin with a wrapping function that would seem to have such functionality, but on close inspection it is way too cumbersome to use if you want to build an efficient snippet library on-the-fly.
Thanks,
Peter Rosti